# setting maxHttpHeaderSize attribute tomcat maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin. Below is the configuration...
My server is getting a request that has more than 8 KB of http headers. 
The default size for maxHttpHeaderSize in tomcat 7 is 8 KB as per this document...

[http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html][1]

How can I increase it using the maven configuration.

pom.xml

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
<path>/</path>
<port>9090</port>   
<httpsPort>9091</httpsPort>
<keystorePass>XX</keystorePass>
<useTestClasspath>false</useTestClasspath>
<systemProperties>
<javax.net.ssl.trustStore>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jssecacerts</javax.net.ssl.trustStore>
<JAVA_OPTS>-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</JAVA_OPTS>
</systemProperties>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out that it is not possible at least in the maven tomcat plugin. The parameter "maxHttpHeaderSize" does not work. We have to do some workaround to get over it.

Comment: Please provide a brief overview of your workaround, so that the solution benefits other users who are facing the same issue.

Comment: How to resolve it?